# Confusion Deployment of website on the IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am a noob. I am learning to develop and deploy small websites on the IIS server. Now i have the following confusion :

I think procedure to 'add' a website to the IIS server starts from adding a new virtual directory or adding a new website in the inetmgr. Please correct me if i am wrong. I also think that once we have done this .. it is mandatory to add the source of the project to the inetpub/wwwroot folder. Am i correct ? Is it always necessary to do so ? I am worried because in that case how can we run multiple websites ? Also .. say i have added a virtual directory to the inetmgr ... now what do i do to run my website ... i am trying but getting "Directory Listing Disabled" written on the browser once i type http:\localhost....\Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No, the source does not need to be added to the Inetpub folder.
You can simply add a new virtual directory pointing to the location of the site.
(Make sure the selected location is the folder containing your Default.aspx page)

If all other settings are correct, you should be able to hit the site at

http://machineName/virtualDirectoryName/

For this address to work, make sure you are allowing default documents, you may have to add "Default.aspx" to the list depending on your IIS version.